# How to parallelize more than one for loop with very heavy computation time in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, computation

```
for a,b in zip(list_x, list_y):
    #computation
    
    for val1, val2, val3 in new_list:
        #computation
```

Here is the example of for loops, I am trying to deal with. Can anyone help me parallelize this whole computation  as currently it is taking more than 5 hours to finish running. Thank you.

Comment: for computation heavy stuff use NumPy

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: look it up on the internet: numpy speedup

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. My concern is more about how to implement multiple processes for such specific type of multiple input arguments. If anyone can guide about that, will be very helpful.